# PHP Sodium Decryption Returns False

Tags: php, libsodium

I am new to php and stackoverflow, thus some mistakes may happen. Please inform me if so and I will resolve them as soon as possible.

My encrypt function:

```
function encrypt($data){
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES);
$ciphertext = sodium_crypto_secretbox($data, $nonce, $GLOBALS['key']);
$ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
$ciphertext .= "[-SPLIT-]" . base64_encode($nonce);

return $ciphertext;}
```

My decrypt function:

```
function decrypt($data){   
$data = explode("[-SPLIT-]", $data);
$ciphertext = base64_decode($data[0]);
$nonce = base64_decode($data[1]);
$plaintext = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($ciphertext, $nonce, $GLOBALS['key']);

if(!$plaintext){$plaintext = "FAILED";}
return $plaintext;}
```

I have done enough testing to know that I am passing the $ciphertext returned from the encrypt function to the decrypt function.

How can I make a function to return a decrypted string that was encrypted in my encrypt function?

Comment: Kindly note that encrypted data (ciphertext) is binary data in most cases so you need to convert the ciphertext to a string-format -> use base64 encoding to get a string and base64-decode the data for later decryption.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, a simple print_r() was messing me up. The above code works as intended, and I will post a few refinements soon.